# Distributed Transactions: When is a commit really done in case of a depending other transaction?

Tags: transactions, distributed-transactions

I know my fair share of transactions and the fluff around it (specialized on it during my university times) but I never got this one right:

I have a set of (distributed) transactions created by two processes (nodes).

In a timely fashion it looks like this:

`P1: |--------------------A----------------------|
 P2: |--------B-------||------------C---------------|`

So now comes the fun part:

***The no interference scenario:***

A gets started and B gets started. B changes something that is never read by A. B commits, C starts and also does not interfer with A, A commits done.

Even if C fails or B fails A can still commit.

***The B depends on A scenario***

A gets started along with B. B now reads something that A has already changed so B depends on A. B commits. Now C starts and A fails resulting in a roll back of C and B.

Since B was committed there is no way of telling if now stalled information set by A was given to the outside since B committed. So I think that B is depending on A and its commit would be delayed to the point in time where A is already committed due it would be a read uncommitted?

***The A depends on B scenario***

Again A and B started. A is reading data that has been changed by B. B commits and C starts. A dies (rolls back), causing C to fail too and get rolled back.

The changes of B are still within the database since they were not depending on something A had already altered.

So from my own perspective if transaction B depends on A and A had not been committed yet, is B delayed in order to wait for A to commit? Same would happen to A when A would depend on C and C takes a bit longer.

Otherwise we would not justify serializability. And that is why some reads can do dirty reads (uncommitted reads / phantom reads) due to avoid delays. Also some other allow reads on snapshots and older versions to also avoid those scenarios.